# How to check if a URL is a Doc or a web page using java

Tags: java, web-crawler, mime

I'm buliding an application similar to a URL crawler wherein I need differentiate between a normal webpage and a pdf or img or doc. Tried all ways of MIMETYPE checks... :(

Comment: Can you use something like HttpClient to do a HEAD request and then read the content type from the response header?

Comment: You should able to figure this from "Content-Type" header.  Show us what you tried, what is failing.

Comment: webpage will be text/html rest will be different, whats failing ?

Comment: public class CheckMIME{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  String URL ="http://deity.gov.in/sites/upload_files/dit/files/AwardedBooks.pdf";
  String URL1 = "http://www.cca.gov.in/cca/";
     System.out.println(validateMimeType(URL1,URL)); 
 }
  
  public static Boolean validateMimeType(String U,String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
   URL u = new URL(url);
   URL u1 = new URL(url);  
   if (u.openConnection().getContentType().equals(u1.openConnection().getContentType())){
    return true;
   }else{
    return false;
   } }}

Comment: I'm getting output as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do the job:

```
URL url = new URL(adress);
URLConnection u = url.openConnection();
String type = u.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
return type;
```

Returns

> text/html; charset=utf-8

for this page.